# Can we create mac version from the iOS version of app

Tags: ios, iphone, macos, operating-system, converters

We develop a iOS and Android version of app. Now need to create a MAC version for same.

Can we direct convert iOS version into the MAC? Is there any need to develop a MAC version from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

Nope. iOS and the Mac share a lot of frameworks, but not enough to do a port without making changes. The biggest thing you'll have to go through is porting all your UIKit code to AppKit code. If your app is something like a game, you may not having very much UIKit code. But otherwise you'll need to do a rewrite with AppKit.

It makes a lot of sense. AppKit handles things like resizable windows, save/open dialogs, multiple windows.... These are all features that UIKit doesn't know anything about that are really required for a Mac app to work well.

Some other frameworks like CoreAnimation, AVFoundation, CoreFoundation, CoreGraphics are either the same or mostly the same, so some of your code will at least be able to port over cleanly. But the biggest pain point is your views and view controllers will need to be redone.